Submission fails on Pre-processing with 5001 error code
I have a published UWP application in Microsoft Store for months with no issues. For the latest updated, I enabled fullTrust capability and packaged my application with another .NET8 WPF application.
When I submit a new submission in Microsoft Partner Center it fails during pre-processing stage with the following error

Link displayed in the message redirects to here which is quite generic support page. I couldn't find anything that describes 5001 error code here.
I've always been uploading .msixupload file. One catch though, old version (only UWP) used to support x86, x64 and ARM32. New submission supports ARM64 instead of ARM32 and x64/x86 as well.
I ran the certification kit on the bundle and no errors were detected. Does anybody know what is this 5001 error code?
